# What do symbols / and || represent in Coq?

Tags: coq

What do the symbols `/` and `||` represent in coq?
I've checked the reference manual and searched the web but couldn't find it.

Comment: really? they are among the first couple of symbols in the [index](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/general-index.html) ;) (the first is division, the other branching)

Comment: usually it division yes (but take this with a grain of salt: I only know the very basics of coq - but the documentation seems to suggest so too)

Comment: Index says so but in Imperative language, c / st can mean "when c is started in the state st", looking in the comments in file Imp.v of Software Foundations book. I'm a beginner in Coq and I get lost easily.

Comment: I have no doubt that you can overload the operators as you want - but still usually `/` = div is a good guess in any language

Comment: This is notation that is defined in the _Software Foundations_ files.  It is not built into Coq.  Look for the 'Notation' commands higher up in the file. In this case   `c1 / st1 || st2` just is a nicer way to write  `(ceval c1 st1 st2)`.

Answer (score 4):

These symbols (like most operators) can be redefined. It depends on the context.

You'll get the most precise answer by asking Coq.

Use e.g. `Locate "||".` to display all the currently notations containing the token `||`.

If you aren't sure which notation is used in a particular expression, ask Coq to print it back with pretty-printing disabled.

```
Unset Printing Notations.
Check (fun a b => a || b).
Set Printing Notations.
```